# How can i get the path of client side download location in java servlet or jsp?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

suppose in my web app user click on download button so a file downloaded into his system. So can i get that client's download location like where the recent downloaded file present in my client system

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get this information. 
It is sandboxed, the server will not be informed by the client about the location.

Comment: so should i have to run some desktop app in client machine to get the path that they have downloaded from my web app?

Comment: You will not get this problem solved, unless you provide the application, which starts the download.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible since you don't have access to user's file system through the browser (JavaScript).

Maybe using a module or whatever directly in the browser.

Comment: so should i have to run some desktop app in client machine to get the path that they have downloaded from my web app?

Answer (score 0):

You don't. All you get is the file name...
What woule it help you anyway as your server does not have the same structure.

Comment: Can u be specific how we can get the file name saved on the client please ?

Comment: so should i have to run some desktop app in client machine to get the path that they have downloaded from my web app?

Comment: This I don't understand. When the client downloads a file you know which file he's asking for, so track it directly on the server. If you are interested on the path the user stored the file on his machine you don't get this information.

Comment: Yes, if you need control and/or information about what exactly the client is doing you need an application on the client. Web based application have no info and/or control over what the client does with downloaded file. Consider the situation: your user selects a file to download from your server (clicks a link) the `save as` dialog is presented to the user, **BUT** the user may choose **NOT** to select the location until the download is completed. Once the download is completed the user disconnects from the internet/network and **NOW** select the location to save the file...